# What is the equivalent of these parameters in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

In windows there are these php.ini parameter values :

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

There is no dll in Ubuntu so what is the equivalent of these parameters in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option  In your php.ini, add the following lines

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no `php` between the `=` sign and `pdo` ?